# Some Post-build event Macros not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsto

The $(OutDir) and $(ConfigurationName) Macro values are empty in my Post-Build event.
My project is a VSTO Office Addin.

Any tips on how to troubleshoot this?

Thanks